# Evernote(Windows) like text editor using Qt

Tags: qt, richtext

Is there any Evernote(Windows) like text editor control available for Qt. I made a comparison between the *Qt's Rich textedit example program* and *Evernote* .

The following image show the copy and paste of [Simple Wiki home page](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) in Qt's textedit example and in Evernote.

**Qt**

[image]

**Evernote**
[image]

The above images clearly shows that Evernote handles Rich text much better that Qt.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if Evernote is using an embedded WebKit browser, together with content editable and an editing toolbar for choosing fonts, etc.

You could do the same.

Comment: It may be good guess but I am not sure about it. But, any way is it possible to embed WebKit browser in Qt's app. If yes where can I find tutorial for that.